# Change values of a column based on existing information of the value?

Tags: r, rename

I have this column

```
faceSex
n
a
f
s
d
h
```

In which I want all the values renamed to this

```
faceSex
neutral
angry
fearful
sad
disgusted
happy
```

So every letter in the first column, corresponds to an emotion in the second, so I guess there should be a way to take advantage of this.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: And I should probably add: The column is much longer than stated above, but in only consists of those 6 letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the full names using the `dplyr` `inner_join` function.  Example:

```
cars <- mtcars
df <- data.frame(cyl = c(4, 6, 8), newcyl = c('foo', 'nork', 'biff'))
inner_join(cars, df, by = 'cyl')
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newcyl
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   nork
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   nork
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    foo
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   nork
5  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   nork
6  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2    foo
7  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2    foo
```

Comment: Oh, that was a clever way to do it! I might go with that one instead of my own solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great.  Please up-vote the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
df$faceEmotion[df$faceEmotion == "n"] <-"neutral"
df$faceEmotion[df$faceEmotion == "f"] <-"fearful"
df$faceEmotion[df$faceEmotion == "s"] <-"sad"
df$faceEmotion[df$faceEmotion == "h"] <-"happy"
df$faceEmotion[df$faceEmotion == "d"] <-"disgusted"
df$faceEmotion[df$faceEmotion == "a"] <-"angry"
```

I'm sure there is a smoother fix, but this works (Y)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `stingr` :

```
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
df1$colname = str_replace(df1$colname,"n","neutral") # and do this for all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `factor` or use a named vector.

Here's `factor`:

```
## Some sample data
set.seed(1); x <- sample(c("n", "a", "f", "s", "d", "h"), 15, TRUE)
x
#  [1] "a" "f" "s" "h" "a" "h" "h" "s" "s" "n" "a" "a" "d" "f" "d"

factor(x, c("n", "a", "f", "s", "d", "h"), 
       c("neutral", "angry", "fearful", "sad", "disgusted", "happy"))
#  [1] angry     fearful   sad       happy     angry     happy     happy    
#  [8] sad       sad       neutral   angry     angry     disgusted fearful  
# [15] disgusted
# Levels: neutral angry fearful sad disgusted happy
```

Here's how you can use named key to match and replace the values. Here's an example:

```
## The named vector of keys
key = c(n = "neutral", a = "angry", f = "fearful",
        s = "sad", d = "disgusted", h = "happy")

## The names of the key is used to match with the value that needs to be
## replaced. By default, the result is a named vector which can be useful
## for verification.
key[x]
#           a           f           s           h           a           h 
#     "angry"   "fearful"       "sad"     "happy"     "angry"     "happy" 
#           h           s           s           n           a           a 
#     "happy"       "sad"       "sad"   "neutral"     "angry"     "angry" 
#           d           f           d 
# "disgusted"   "fearful" "disgusted" 

## Remove the names and just keep the results by using "unname"
unname(key[x])
#  [1] "angry"     "fearful"   "sad"       "happy"     "angry"     "happy"    
#  [7] "happy"     "sad"       "sad"       "neutral"   "angry"     "angry"    
# [13] "disgusted" "fearful"   "disgusted"
```

This approach is easy to maintain. Here's an example of dealing with a new value:

```
## Values not in the key become NA
x <- c(x, "l")
unname(key[x])
#  [1] "angry"     "fearful"   "sad"       "happy"     "angry"     "happy"    
#  [7] "happy"     "sad"       "sad"       "neutral"   "angry"     "angry"    
# [13] "disgusted" "fearful"   "disgusted" NA   

## You can easily append the new value to the original key.
## A replacement can be matched to more than one key. Here, for example,
## I've mapped the key value of "l" to a replacement of "neutral". Thus,
## if a value is either "n" or "l", it will be replaced with "neutral"
key2 = c(key, l = "neutral")
unname(key2[x])
#  [1] "angry"     "fearful"   "sad"       "happy"     "angry"     "happy"    
#  [7] "happy"     "sad"       "sad"       "neutral"   "angry"     "angry"    
# [13] "disgusted" "fearful"   "disgusted" "neutral"
```